# Ways of calculating something of the sort $||f_n-f||_{\infty}$ faster

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

If I define on $[0,1]$, $f_n(x)=x^n$. Then the pointwise limit $f$ exists and is given by $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &,\quad  x \in [0,1) \\ 1 &,\quad x=1\end{cases}$$

Convergence is not uniform, since we have $||f_n-f||_{\infty}=1$ for all $n$.

So, I would just like to check whether my thinking is right in the process of  calculating the $||f_n-f||_{\infty}= \sup |f_n-f|$

So, Sup $|f_n-f|=$ $\sup|x^n-1|$

For $n=1$ $|x^1-1|$ takes max value $|-1|=1$ for $x \in [0,1]$

For $n=2$ $|x^2-1|$ take max value $|-1|=1$ for $x \in [0,1]$

And so on for every $n$

So, this is the right way to deduce this? Is there a faster, more creative way? Or do I have to compute the supremum manually until at some point, I just do it in my head really quickly (ie just have enough experience that I do it very quick)?

Comment: You have a typo. $f(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x\in [0,1) \\ 1, & x = 1\end{cases}$. The first case does not include $x=1$. Additionally, $\sup|f_n-f| \neq \sup|x^n-1|$ as $f$ is not constantly equal to $1$. $\sup|f_n-f| = \sup\{|x^n-0|: x \in [0,1)\} = \sup\{|x^n|: x \in [0,1)\}$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe why is $|f_n-f|=|x^n-0|$?

Comment: Because for all $x \in [0,1)$, $f(x) = 0$ and $f_n(x) = x^n$. And $f_n(1) = f(1) = 1$. You wind up with the exact same answer. For every $n$, $\sup|x^n| = 1$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe ok, but when $x =1$ then $f(x)=1$ ? So the sup of $f(x)$ is $1$?

Comment: That is not how $\sup$ works. Writing it out fully, it would be: $\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$. you are looking for the pointwise difference. Again, you get the same answer. The supremum of the distance between the two functions for any $n$ is still $1$. But, your calculation was not representative of what that is the case.

Comment: What Joe said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to figure out how to compute
$$
\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}
$$
where $f$ takes two values, $0$ on $[0,1)$ and $1$ if $x=1$; moreover $f_{n}(x)=x^n$.

Now since $f_{n}(1)-f(1)=1-1=0$, the supremum has to be considered on $[0,1)$.

But on this interval $f$ is $0$, thus

$$
\|f_{n}-f\|_{\infty,[0,1]}
=\|f_{n}-f\|_{\infty,[0,1)}
=\|f_{n}\|_{\infty,[0,1)}
=\sup_{x\in[0,1)}x^n
$$
and the latter is clearly 1.